# Session Start and End ASP.NET is there a way to capture a value immediately before it is cleared?

Tags: asp.net, session, session-variables, sessionend

A fairly simple question really.

I am trying to hold a series of values in a Cached object, which is populated via a range of session objects.

It isn't, but we can kind of think of it as like a chat system.

There are multiple users, signed in on multiple machines, therefore multiple session states should exist.

In order to give a multi-user view, the master collection is held in the cache (so it can be viewed across the multiple sessions)

When a new machine starts a new session, the cache object is updated, but when a session ends, I need to be able to remove an item by Key from the Cache, but the key will be lost AFTER session ends!

So... is there any way to grab a value immediately before a session ends?

Comment: Store in `application` object instead of `session` object

Comment: BTW: the answer to your original question is to use `Session_End` in `global.asax`. The session variables will be lost only after this event is completed. I suggested `application` state in lieu of cache.